# How to migrate thick client to the cloud

Tags: api, architecture, microservices

Current situation:

- Thick client wrote in .NET
- We have a very old computation software that we can't maintain anymore.
- We don't really know how the kernel is working (people left, 15 years old code).
- We have the code and some technical experts.

We want to migrate it to the cloud behind a public API in order to serve some SPA application or even thick client applications.

What is you recommendation about that problem?

We have thought about:

1. Lift-n-Shift
2. Lift-Adjust-n-Shift
3. Rearchitecting or redeveloping from the ground
4. Repurchasing a new cloud solution (but it doesn't seem to have any)

Answer (score 0):

All options that you mentioned are possible but which one to choose really depends on your business needs time and budget.

**Lift and shift (vms)**

This is mostly quickest approach and you may simply use VMs to migrate to cloud.  But managing VMs is your responsibility and is on going committment.

**Lift adjust and shift (containers)**

in my opinion you get benefits of cloud when you start using PAAS services.  You may consider containerize (docker) your application and migrate it to cloud and start using paas services. your dev ops cycle will be quick and scaling is easy.  Since you are not managing vms anymore it's less hassle.

**rearchitect amd redevlop**

this could be costly and time consuming and really depends if your business requirements allow you to do that. if you plan to expand the existing code base then you may consider this else it could be big deal when you can simply migrate your services using approaches mentioned above.